# ImportError: cannot import name 'VectorStoreIndex' from 'llama_index' (unknown location)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker, huggingface, llama-index

I ran into this problem when I was trying to import the following libraries and it is giving the error "ImportError: cannot import name 'VectorStoreIndex' from 'llama_index' (unknown location)"

I ran this exact same code in the morning and it worked perfectly.

I did `!pip install llama_index`

```
from llama_index import VectorStoreIndex, SimpleDirectoryReader, ServiceContext
from llama_index.llms import HuggingFaceLLM
from llama_index.prompts.prompts import SimpleInputPrompt
```

I tried commenting out first line and faced same issue for HuggingFaceLLM module
Same issue for SimpleInputPrompt, got error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'llama_index.prompts'"

First I faced the problem in a sagemaker notebook so I thought the issue was with the sagemaker notebook so I spun up a clean new notebook and I got the same error.
So, I tried the code in my local Jypiter notebook, google collab notebook, sagemaker studiolab notebook and I got the same error.

Answer (score 11):

The llama index library was recently updated so I was able to solve the issue by using updating the import according to the documentation

```
from llama_index.core import VectorStoreIndex,SimpleDirectoryReader,ServiceContext,PromptTemplate
from llama_index.llms.huggingface import HuggingFaceLLM
```

https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/examples/customization/llms/SimpleIndexDemo-Huggingface_stablelm.html

Answer (score 2):

Llamaindex constantly changes the modules directories.

The module you are searching for is:

from llama_index.core import VectorStoreIndex

And for an especific vectorstore using chromadb as example, you need to install:

pip install llama-index-vector-stores-chroma

and would be imported as follows

from llama_index.vector_stores.chroma import ChromaVectorStore

Source: https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/examples/vector_stores/chroma_metadata_filter.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this error occurs because of pip installation.
I encounterd the same error, and I figured out this error could be simply fixed with pip installation.

Would you check if the same error occurs when just after remove all llama-* related package and just re-install llama-index?

```
pip chache purge
```

This command will help that pip does not install previously installed cached package.

And if you encounter the same error with import, refer to the other installation method, like using git.
This documents would be helpful.
https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html

Comment: I tried this and I am still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

As Lat mentioned above, llama_index was updated and requires llama_index.core import to solve (unknown location) error. I ran into this trying to import PromptTemplates.

Answer (score 0):

`from llama_index.core.indices.vector_store.base import VectorStoreIndex` worked for me

Source: https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/api_reference/indices/vector_store.html